# Let my Firebase application trigger microservice exclusively

Tags: firebase, authentication, jwt, microservices

I have a Google VM running my dockerized application and i also have my Firebase front end application.

I want my Firebase application to trigger my microservice. The thing is, i want to be security conscious and i want the Firebase app to be the only actor who can trigger the microservice.

What is the best option for such a task?
The only thing i have found are json web tokens (jwts). Is this good enough for the job? Is there something better?

If jwts are what is needed, then what is the logic that the code should have?
Should the server create a key and send it to the microservice, then the microservice should decode it and only if it matches a value it should proceed with the job?

Comment: The new [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) feature was made for this sort of thing, but I don't think the server-side API for it is ready yet.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks! But when you mean server-side, you mean the microservice side (as opposed to the firebase side). Did i unerstand it correctly?

Comment: Correct. App Check currently allows specific Firebase services to only allow traffic from apps that are registered in the project, you are looking for the other side of that: only allow traffic from those apps to **your** services. That *is* something considered for App Check, just not yet. Also see https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/rU0fEozdMyc/m/AYUa6PpLCAAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The new [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) feature was made for this sort of thing, but how to access such app tokens from your own server-side code isn't decided yet.

So App Check currently allows specific Firebase services to only allow traffic from apps that are registered in the project. You are looking for the other side of that: only allow traffic from those apps to **your** services, which is not supported yet.

Also see https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/rU0fEozdMyc/m/AYUa6PpLCAAJ

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any suggestion on how i can procceed now though?

Comment: After researching more, i came across this subject: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc. Is it a possible option for access control of the microservice to the Firebase server?

Answer (score 2):

Firebaser here.

I'm actually not entirely sure of your architecture, but if you are looking to reduce abuse to your own server that serves your Firebase app on Android, iOS, or Web, then yes, we are working on supporting this use case in [App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check).

However, App Check is *not* for securing server-to-server communication (both servers under your control). On Google Cloud this is done typically using Service Accounts and IAM controls.

With that out of the way, assuming you want the first thing and not the second thing, and assuming you don't want to wait for the official support to be ready, there is in fact a way for you to do this now, but you will have to do a lot of work yourself. Also, since App Check is currently in Beta, it can change in ways that are backwards incompatible and is not subject to any SLA or deprecation policy.

For obtaining the App Check token, you can make a POST to these endpoints. These are actually the same endpoints used by the SDKs under the hood, so you can study their source to see examples of how these calls are made. You should also follow their example to periodically re-attest the app and re-obtain App Check tokens, based on the expiration of the returned App Check token.

*[edit: Make sure to register your apps in App Check first. See our [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) here.]*

- For DeviceCheck, use `https://firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/<project_number>/apps/<app_id>:exchangeDeviceCheckToken?key=<api_key>`

  - the body should be a JSON object with a single string field, `device_token`. This is the `device_token` as returned by Apple's client-side [DeviceCheck API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/dcdevice). This is the Base64 encoded `Data` (Swift) or `NSData` (ObjC) object.
- For reCAPTCHA v3, use `https://firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/<project_number>/apps/<app_id>:exchangeRecaptchaToken?key=<api_key>`

  - the body should be a JSON object with a single string field, `recaptcha_token`. This is the reCAPTCHA token as returned by the [reCAPTCHA v3 JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3).
- For SafetyNet, use `https://firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/<project_number>/apps/<app_id>:exchangeSafetyNetToken?key=<api_key>`

  - the body should be a JSON object with a single string field, `safety_net_token`. This is the [SafetyNet attestation response](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation#request-attestation-step) issued to your app.
- For Custom providers, follow the instructions from our [public documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-provider). However, you will not be using the App Check SDK in your app. Instead, you need to write code directly to contact your token server.

These endpoints will reject the request with `403 Forbidden` if their corresponding token is invalid. Your client should only retry a small finite number of times upon this type of failure since the situation will likely not change, and if you do retry, you should also rerun the entire attestation flow with the corresponding attestation provider.

Once your app has received an App Check token via the above, you should attach it to every request made to an API (on your server) that you want to protect. For example, you can send the App Check token via a header. Once your server receives such a request, use the [Admin SDK Verify Token API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.appCheck.AppCheck-1#verifytoken) to verify this token. For example,

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

async function verifyToken(token) {
  admin.appCheck().verifyToken(token)
    .then((token) => {
      console.log(token.token)
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e))
}
```

This Verify Token API is in fact what our Callable Functions SDK uses under the hood. If the token is invalid, your server should reject the request.

Note that this Verify Token API can make a GET call--but is then cached for a period of time--to our public keys endpoint, so keep that in mind if you have limited bandwidth, limited CPU cycles, or no caching at token verification time:

- `https://firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com/v1beta/jwks`

  - This returns a JWK set as specified by [Section 5 of RFC 7517](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7517#section-5) containing the public keys that can be used to verify our App Check tokens.

Again, we are working on making it possible for you to retrieve the App Check token directly from the App Check SDK, so that you don't have to manage the periodic refresh or the POST requests yourself. Stay tuned for this feature in the upcoming month.

Comment: Thank you for the post! It is a great reference. What i want essentially, is my flask server running on a docker container in a Google VM, to only accept calls from my Firebase app an exclude all other requests from other parties.

Comment: After researching more, i came across this subject: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc. Is it a possible option for access control of the microservice to the Firebase server?